# StopIteration Error in pythoncode while reading csv data

Tags: python, csv, iterator

I am writing a program to read csv file. I have craeted a reader object and calling next() on it gives me the header row. But when I am calling it again it gives StopIteration error although there are rows in the csv file.I am doing file.seek(0) then it is working fine. Anyone please explains this to me? A snapshot of code is given below:

```
with open(file,'r') as f:
     reader = csv.reader(f)
     header = next(reader)
     result = []
     for colname in header[2:]:
             col_index = header.index(colname)     
   #          f.seek(0)
             next(reader)
```

Comment: yes is it related to os

Comment: As a side note, you should never do `for foo in bar: index = bar.index(foo)`. This is slow, and complicated, and potentially buggy (what happens if two columns have the same name?). Just do `for index, foo in enumerate(bar):`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling `next` once for each column (except the first two). So, if you have, say, 10 columns, it's going to try to read 8 rows.

If you have 20 rows, that's not going to raise an exception, but you'll be ignoring the last 12 rows, which you probably don't want. On the other hand, if you have only 5 rows, it's going to raise when trying to read the 6th row.

The reason the `f.seek(0)` prevents the exception is that it resets the file back to the start before each `next`, so you just read the header row over and over, ignoring everything else in the file. It doesn't raise anything, but it's not doing useful.

What you probably wanted is something like this:

```
with open(file,'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header = next(reader)
    result = []
    for row in reader:
        for col_index, colname in enumerate(header)[2:]:
            value = row[col_index]
            result.append(do_something_with(value, colname))
```

This reads every row exactly once, and does something with each column but the first two of each row.

---

From a comment, what you actually want to do is find the maximum value for each column. So, you do need to iterate over the columns–and then, within each column, you need to iterate over the rows.

A `csv.reader` is an iterator, which means you can only iterate over it once. So, if you just do this the obvious way, it won't work:

```
maxes = {}
with open(file) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header = next(reader)
    for col_index, colname in enumerate(header)[2:]:
        maxes[colname] = max(reader, key=operator.itemgetter(col_index))
```

The first column will read whatever's left after reading the header, which is good. The next column will read whatever's left after reading the whole file, which is nothing.

---

So, how can you fix this?

One way is to re-create the iterator each time through the outer loop:

```
maxes = {}
with open(file) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header = next(reader)
for col_index, colname in enumerate(header)[2:]:
    with open(file) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        next(reader)
        maxes[colname] = max(reader, key=lambda row: float(row[col_index]))
```

The problem with this is that you're reading the whole file N times, and reading the file off disk is probably by far the slowest thing your program does.

---

What you were attempting to do with `f.seek(0)` is a trick that depends on how file objects and `csv.reader` objects work. While file objects are iterators, they're special, in that they have a way to reset them to the beginning (or to save a position and return to it later). And `csv.reader` objects are basically simple wrappers around file objects, so if you reset the file, you also reset the reader. (It's not clear that this is guaranteed to work, but if you know how `csv` works, you can probably convince yourself that in practice it's safe.) So:

```
maxes = {}
with open(file) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header = next(reader)
    for col_index, colname in enumerate(header)[2:]:
        f.seek(0)
        next(reader)
        maxes[colname] = max(reader, key=lambda row: float(row[col_index]))
```

This saves you the cost of closing and opening the file each time, but that's not the expensive part; you're still doing the disk reads over and over. And now anyone reading your code has to understand the trick with using file objects as iterators but resetting them, or they won't know how your code works.

---

So, how can you avoid that?

In general, whenever you need to make multiple passes over an iterator, there are two options. The simple solution is to copy the iterator into a reusable iterable, like a list:

```
maxes = {}
with open(file) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header = next(reader)
    rows = list(reader)
for col_index, colname in enumerate(header)[2:]:
    maxes[colname] = max(rows, key=lambda row: float(row[col_index]))
```

This is not only much simpler than the earlier code, it's also much faster. Unless the file is huge. By storing all of the rows in a list, you're reading the whole file into memory at once. If it's too big to fit, your program will fail. Or, worse, if it fits, but only by using virtual memory, your program will swap parts of it in and out of memory every time you go through the loop, thrashing your swapfile and making everything slow to a crawl.

---

The other alternative is to reorganize things so you only have to make one pass. This means you have to put the loop over the rows on the outside, and the loop over the columns on the inside. It requires rethinking the design a bit, and it means you can't just use the simple `max` function, but the tradeoff is probably worth it:

```
with open(file) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header = next(reader)
    maxes = {colname: float('-inf') for colname in header[2:]}
    for row in reader:
        for col_index, colname in enumerate(header)[2:]:
            maxes[colname] = max(maxes[colname], float(row[col_index]))
```

You can simplify this even further—e.g., use a `Counter` instead of a plain `dict`, and a `DictReader` instead of a plain `reader`—but it's already simple, readable, and efficient as-is.

Comment: Hi Abarnert,Thanks for ur reply.What I am trying to do is for every column i have to find the maximum value.So i was using the max() generator expression for every column. can you give me some hint of the code

Comment: @maverick: Meanwhile, in the future, please give a more complete example that shows what you were actually trying to do, and enough input that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much.I will be more precise about the problems in the future

Answer (score 1):

For me Was accidentally remove data (there is no data) in **.csv**
so get this message.

> so make sure to check if there is data in **.csv** file or not.

Answer (score -1):

Why didn't you write:

```
header = next(reader)
```

In the last line as well? I don't know if this is your problem, but I would start there.